# How to format the date and time from a date time picker

Tags: react-native, datetime, expo

I am currently working on a reminders app and I added a `DateTimePickerModal` from the package `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` and I wanted to know how to format the data...

This is the code for the component

```
<DateTimePickerModal
    isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
    mode="datetime"
    onConfirm={onConfirm}
    onCancel={onCancel}                                                                                                        
/>
```

Code for the `onConfirm` function

```
const onConfirm = (dateAndTime) => {
     this.setState({ dateAndTime: dateAndTime.toString() });
     hideModal();                   
};
```

The data I'm getting:

```
Converted into string: Mon May 03 2021 16:01:37 GMT+0530 (IST)

Without converting it to string: 2021-05-06T09:31:37.000Z
```

If you have any idea on how to do this please let me know...Thanks in advance!

Comment: react-native datetime picker returns `Date` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date So, you can use the built-in methods to format your date https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803/5793132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are on the right way

Just create a function to format Date like this

```js
const FormatDate = (data) => {
  let dateTimeString =
    data.getDate() +
    '-' +
    (data.getMonth() + 1) +
    '-' +
    data.getFullYear() +
    ' ' +
    data.getHours() +
    ':' +
    data.getMinutes();

  return dateTimeString; // It will look something like this 3-5-2021 16:23
};
```

Then for setting state do like this

```js
this.setState({ dateAndTime: FormatDate(dateAndTime) });
```

Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/date-time-format) to see a working example. It will run on iOS and Android only as

**`DateTimePicker is not supported on: web`**

Comment: Thank you so much @Kartikey Vaish...I tried it and it worked 